# Why does my alt tag not work at showing a description when hovering the image?

Tags: html, image

I've tried both the longdesc and the alt tag to make it so a description of the image appears when hovering it but none of them seem to work.

Any idea what to do since none of the tags seem to work.

My code currently looks like this:

```
<div align="center">
<img src="placeholder.jpg" width="900" height="300" alt="Placeholder">
</div>
```

Comment: Use the `title` attribute instead. `alt` is for when the image fails to load and screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

The `alt` attribute stands for alternative text when the image doesn't load for any reason. The correct attribute you are looking for is `title`.

```
<img src="placeholder.jpg" width="900" height="300" title="Placeholder">
```